# Error while using predict

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, logistic-regression, data-science-model

After splitting into test and train the glm function is used on train set. For example

```
m1 = glm(target ~ ., data = train, family="binomial")
```

Then

```
P = predict(m1,newdata=test, type="response")
```

Here I am getting warning message :

> newdata has 60000 rows but variables found have 100000 rows

And the next step:

```
table(test$target, P>0.5)
```

Here I am getting error:

> all arguments must have same length

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Works find for me. Maybe you have some error in the definition of the train/test set?

```
library(ISLR)
library(glmnet)
# Load data
iris = iris[iris$Species=="Setosa" | iris$Species=="versicolor",]
iris$Species = as.factor(iris$Species)
# Make a test/train split
set.seed(123)
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(iris))
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(iris)), size = smp_size)
train <- iris[train_ind, ]
test <- iris[-train_ind, ]

m1 = glm(Species ~ ., data = train, family="binomial")
p = predict(m1,newdata=test, type="response")
table(test$Species, p>0.5)
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: worked like a charm on my computer

Comment: I am getting the same error